# the use of 'but'

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

> There is no mother but loves her children.
>
> There is scarcely a man but has a weak point.

I read these sentences, and I guess 'but' means 'who does not'.

Is it correct?

May I use 'but' as in the above sentences in formal writing?

Comment: The use of "but" in the sense of "who doesn't" seems unidiomatic. "Why don't you use "who doesn't"  instead?

Comment: What is the source of these quotations?

Answer (score 1):

The usage of 'but' indicated in the question appears archaic and unusual.  Therefore, such formulations might confuse a reader and get wrongly or poorly understood.  They also might give an undesired impression of your writing style.